# Add filename to appended text file in shell script above pasted text

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, gawk

Working on a script (Mac OSX Yosemite, working in Terminal), where I analyse a lot of files and where I want to add the output of the script in one text file.

```
gawk -f ./user/filter.dat ./user/outputpre1.out >> ./user/outputpost.out
gawk -f ./user/filter.dat ./user/outputpre2.out >> ./user/outputpost.out
```

For interpretation finding the source of the output is very useful. The output I have right now is all just rows, like this:

```
ROW1:OUTPUTOUTPUT
ROW2:OUTPUTOUTPUT
ROW8:OUTPUTOUTPUT
ROW10:OUTPUTOUTPUT
```

What I want:

```
**Output from file outputpre1.out
ROW1:OUTPUTOUTPUT
ROW2:OUTPUTOUTPUT

**Output from file outputpre2.out
ROW8:OUTPUTOUTPUT
ROW10:OUTPUTOUTPUT
```

Is that possible via gawk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not show the `filter.dat` script, but `gawk` does know the name of the current input-file, which can be incorporated into the logic of your script (see [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Built_002din-Variables)):

> **FILENAME**
>
> The name of the current input file.  If no files are specified on the command line, the value  of  **FILENAME**  is  “-”.
>   However,  **FILENAME**  is  undefined  inside  the  **BEGIN** block
>   (unless set by getline).

*How* it would be incorporated depends on how `filter.dat` is organized.  The script would have to set a variable (which would be tested on repeated uses) to ensure that it prints the filename once only.  Something like this fragment:

```
BEGIN {
    first = 1
}
... (just before printing rows)
if (first == 1) {
    printf "\n**Output from file %s\n", FILENAME;
    first = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The filter.dat is easily organized.

`{    if ($21 > 0.005) {
     }
     else {
     print $0
     }
}`

Comment: Right now I manage to add the filename, by adding it after the "print $0" command. I am only not sure where to put the rest of this code in this filter.dat file.